# Is there a polynomial algorithm to solve the problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, integer-programming

Suppose that $v_1,\ldots,v_m\in\mathbb{C}^d$ satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^mv_iv_i^*=I_d$. Consider the optimization problem
$$
\operatorname{min} \bigg\|\sum_{i=1}^m\varepsilon_iv_iv_i^*\bigg\|\\
s.t. \quad\varepsilon_i\in\{-1,+1\} ,\\
i=1,2,\ldots,m,
$$
where the norm is matrix spectral norm. The objective function describes the least discrepancy of the two groups of the matrices partitioned in $\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$.
Is there a polynomial algorithm to solve the integer programming?

Comment: I suspect you're confused about the meaning of "NP-hard". For one you need to ask about a decision problem, whereas you're asking about finding a particular solution. For another it's very unclear how you'd specify your problem in some number of bits, given that you've got complex numbers in the problem input which could theoretically take infinitely many bits to specify.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson Yeah, you are right. I also want to ask whether there exsits a polynomial time algorithm to solve the integer programming.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to rethink what your actual problem is and update the question afterwards (or maybe ask a new one). A complexity forum may be more appropriate as well.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson, I think it is fairly easy/standard to interpret this as a decision problem. TSP is also often formulated as "what is the shortest path?"; the decision version is simply "is there a path of length at most $l$?" The complex numbers don't seem to be too problematic either: the function to be optimized is Lipschitz continuous, so we can ask for an error that goes to zero reasonably fast as more bits of the inputs $v_i$ are given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the special case $d=1$ and $v_1, ..., v_m \in \mathbb{R}$. Then your assumption is $\sum_{i=1}^m v_i^2 = 1$ and your objective function is $\min |\sum_{i=1}^m \epsilon_i v_i^2|$.

This is a version of the optimization version of the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), so it is NP-hard. Specifically, you can transform any instance $a_1, ..., a_m \in \mathbb{N}$ of the partition problem into one satisfying your constraints by defining $v_i = \sqrt{\frac{a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^m a_i}}$.

If you want to enforce $d>1$, you can transform an instance $a_1, …, a_m \in \mathbb{N}$ of the partition problem into an instance of your problem as follows. Set the first coordinate of each $v_i$ to $\sqrt{\frac{a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^m a_i}}$ and set all other coordinates to zero. Then $v_i v_i^*$ is a $d \times d$ matrix with $(1,1)$ the only non-zero entry. Then $\|\sum_{i=1}^m \epsilon_i v_i v_i^*\|$ is just $|\sum_{i=1}^m \epsilon_i (v_i)_1 (v_i)_1|$, so the optimization problem is the same as in the case $d=1$.

However, with this construction $\sum_{i=1}^m v_i v_i^* \neq I_d$. To fix this, add to the instance of your problem additional vectors $v_{m+1}, …, v_{m+2d-2}$ with $v_{m+2i-3} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} e_i$ and $v_{m+2i-2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e_i$ for $i=2,…,d$. This ensures that $\sum_{i=1}^{m+2d-2} v_i v_i^* = I_d$. Furthermore, the optimal value of the objective does not change, because you can just choose $\epsilon_{m+2i-3}=-\epsilon_{m+2i-2}$ to cancel the contributions of each pair of vectors $v_{m+2i-3}$ and $v_{m+2i-2}$ for $i=2,...d$.

Therefore, a solution to your problem that could solve such instances would yield a solution to the partition problem. So your problem is NP-hard.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It looks correct to me.

Comment: So the conclusion is that the problem in general is NP-hard ?  To do that, we have to make sure that the case of $d>1$ is more complex than $d=1$.

Comment: @Rockafellar Well, the problem statement does not exclude $d=1$, so the answer is sufficient to show that the problem as stated is NP-hard. Nevertheless, I updated the answer to include a reduction that works for $d>1$.